# Extraction of Cloud Coverage percentages of Sentinel 2 images

Tags: qgis, python, sentinel-2, sentinel-hub

I have to download S2A images over a large area from 2016 March to 2019 January. Before start downloading data, first I want to know cloud coverage percentages of all the images over this period.

Is there any way to do it either on QGIS or using python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try s2cloudless Python package:
https://github.com/sentinel-hub/sentinel2-cloud-detector
More info here:
https://medium.com/sentinel-hub/sentinel-hub-cloud-detector-s2cloudless-a67d263d3025

If you are only interested in rough estimates, there are some faster options:
https://www.sentinel-hub.com/faq/best-way-do-cloud-filtering-specific-aoi

(disclaimer: I am working at Sentinel Hub project; the resources above require subscription, but you should be able to to it within the limits of a free trial account)